# coding for repetitive increase

Tags: matlab

In the following code, I want `a` and `b` to increase by 1 each time the calculations are done. Can someone please have a look:

```
for t = 1:20

    a = 2;
    b = 2;

    r = a + b;

    if r<5
        display('reaching target')

    elseif r>5
        disp('job done')

    end

    a = a+1;
    b = b+1;

end
```

If I run this, it'll show me reaching target 20 times on screen, meaning for `t = 1`, `a = 2`, `b = 2`, and `r = 4` which is less than 5 so displaying reaching target is true. Next step, `t = 2`, I want `a` to increase to 3 from 2 and `b = 3` as well (increment by 1), and then `r = 6` which is greater than 5 so it should display `'job done'`, but it's not doing that. What is wrong?

Comment: I can see that a and b do increase by 1. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Please describe the intended behaviour!

Comment: so if i run this, it'll show me reaching target 20 times on screen. meaning for t = 1, a = 2, b = 2, and r = 4 which is less than 5 so displaying reaching target is true. next step, t = 2, I want a to increase to 3 from 2 and b = 3 as well (increment by 1). and then r = 6 which is greater than 5 so it should display job done, but its not doing that. I am really confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reassigning the value 2 to both `a` and `b` at every start of the loop, `r` is always going to be equal to 4. Take the initialization of `a` and `b` out of the loop.

```
a = 2;
b = 2;   
for t = 1:20
     r = a + b;

     if r<5
         display('reaching target')

     elseif r>5
         disp('job done')

     end

     a = a+1;
     b = b+1;

end
```

Comment: one more thing, lets say if my a is a set of values like a is (x,y) and b is also (m,n). then how can i increase x,y,m,n by 1 in each step? thanks

Comment: @user3276258 it will work as is. Matlab automatically distribute additions on elements of vectors. So `[1 2]+1 = [2 3]`

Comment: but then i want it to add x and m separately and y and n separately and then calculate r using sqrt((x+m)^2 + (y+n)^2). which i think might it is not doing?

Comment: @user3276258 compute `r=sqrt(sum((a - b) .^ 2))` as I imagine you need the euclidian distance. Your equation would be `sqrt(sum((a+b) .^ 2))`